# Database design for different kinds of userprofiles in SQL Server

Tags: database-design

I have a web application where I have 2 kinds of users: teachers and others. I have created a usertable where the accountinfo resides. with accountinfo, I mean emailaddress, username, password, lastactivitydate etc. Each user has a profile and a profile contains data like age, aboutme, address etc, so this info is in nature different from what is in the user table, that's why I have a separate UserProfile table with a FK of UserId pointing back to the user table.

I was quite happy with this design till I realized that the profile for a teacher has more fields then for others (the others may get additional fields that differ from those of teachers also in the future). For a teacher, I need for example his school etc. So then I would have an additional TeacherProfile table containing the extra data. So that would mean that I would do a join between 3 tables to get all the data for a teacher: User, BaseUserProfile, TeacherProfile. So I am wondering if it was a good idea to separate the base userprofile data to a separate table, of should I merge that table with the User table? What other options are there for this problem?

Comment: Cross posted: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44210

Answer (score 1):

> 2 kinds of users

These are usually called `roles`. So you would normally  have these tables:

- tblUser

  - UserId (PK)
  - RoleId (FK)
  - Email
  - LastLoggedIn
  - PasswordHash
  - Salt
- tblUserProfile

  - UserProfileId (PK)
  - UserId (FK)
  - Contains columns for both teachers and students, some values will be `NULL` for students
- tblUserRole

  - RoleId (PK)
  - RoleName

I understand that this is likely to be a learning task, but even there start using good security practices - do not store passwords (encrypted or not) at all. Instead store secure hash of the password and salt used to generate the hash.

Comment: - About the passwords: of course I dont' save plain passwords, I didn't want to elaborate on that. - roles won't do as I need to store additional profile data!

Comment: Storing the salt with the hash makes the hash less secure.  It's better to use some other field as a salt or use a salt that can be generated easily.

Comment: @user24790 tblUserProfile will have all the columns related to profiles (basic + additional). If it is a student, then the additional columns will be `NULL`. If it is a teacher - then the columns may contain some additional values. Make sense?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I don't agree on that. Storing salt side by side with hash doesn't make it insecure. It just says for this particular password use this random junk to generate hash. Using another field for this adds complexity and obfuscation (but no security value per se). I am not sure generating salt is more secure than just storing it. If you can easily reproduce it, what's the point of generation if I can just do it once and store it.

Comment: Well guys, thanks for the answers, but the password stuff isn't that relevant here. @oleksii: Your suggestion violates the first normal form of database design. It will also not make the querying easier, as you have to check which role the user has, so a simple join is not sufficient. Of course, you can always get all the columns from the tblUserProfile table with a join, but then somewhere in your code you have to handle this anomaly.

Comment: @user24790 Can you please explain 1NF violation? None of the the  domains have elements which are sets, what am I overlooking?

Comment: @oleksii: 1NF says "all instances of an entity must contain the same number of values". So if you have a table where you save data for teachers and non-teachers, not all the records will contain the same fields. This is my understanding of it.